# is base-64 just for jpeg or gif? how about a tiff? how can I convert string (which is part of XML and belong to a tiff file) to byte[]?

Tags: arrays, base64, tiff

I want to save and load a TIFF Image with the base64 encoded content:

```
byte[] b = convert.frombase64("ADFsf/s1ugdGHREHR/+/235gjhjhfcg/+kdhjgvkhfv/gcngcxsfdzsdf......=")

file.writeallbytes("z.tiff",b);
```

but I can not open it ,It doesn`t save correctly.
I received this message on loading the tiff Image:

```
run-time error '31037'
system error &H800401C2 (-2147221054)
```

Comment: "It doesn't work and had got an error" doesn't provide much information for us to help you. Update the question with the actual error message or stack trace. It would also be helpful if you posted an example of the XML with the base64 encoded content.

Comment: I  edited    ---> thank you

Comment: Is the base64 data in your question real input? If I decode it from base64, the data in `b` doesn't seem very much like a TIFF, so trying to load it will fail. A TIFF must always start with a byte order mark "II" (Intel or Little endian) or "MM" (Motorola or Big endian), and the number 42 in the given byte order.

Comment: dear haraldk  : I wrote this decoded string just as a sample . well  this is real ,but just first of it : "TU0AKgAAAAgCQEAAA ....."

Comment: No, you said that in a comment to one of the answers. It's still wrong in the question. And even if it's just an example, you should use one that can reproduce the problem you are facing. The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) clearly states: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself* to be on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Base-64 is certainly not only for JPEG or GIF. It can be used to represent any string of binary data (including plain text.) The base-64-encoded data you gave is malformed (as can be seen by writing the bytestream to a .tiff file), though.

Comment: The base-64-encoded data that I wrote is for an example  thnks

Answer (score 0):

My issue was done!

```
byte[] b = convert.frombase64("ADFsf/s1ugdGHREHR/+/235gjhjhfcg/+kdhjgvkhfv/gcngcxsfdzsdf......=")
```

method: `convert.frombase64` -> can be used  for any string of binary data

My problem was about loading a tiff file.
Firstly I must identify the pages in tiff image.
I split my tiff image to single pages by frame dimension method.